# jQuery UI - Draggable issue with Zoom

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm facing an issue while dragging the elements inside canvas, here my canvas is div. Inside  a div I have two draggable elements. I just applied a zoom property for those draggable elements. I would have applied the zoom for a parent div but based on the requirement I should apply zoom only for the draggable element. However after applying the zoom for the draggable elements it's not responding well, when I try to move it to the edge(both X & Y) of the canvas. I tried some calculation but it's working.

```js
var zoom = $('#canvas').css('zoom');
var canvasHeight = $('#canvas').height();
var canvasWidth = $('#canvas').width();

$('#dragme').draggable({
    drag: function(evt,ui)
  {
        // zoom fix
    //    ui.position.top = Math.round(ui.position.top / zoom);
    //    ui.position.left = Math.round(ui.position.left / zoom);
        
        // don't let draggable to get outside of the canvas
       if (ui.position.left < 0) 
           ui.position.left = 0;
      if (ui.position.left + $(this).width() > canvasWidth)
           ui.position.left = canvasWidth - $(this).width();  
      if (ui.position.top < 0)
            ui.position.top = 0;
        if (ui.position.top + $(this).height() > canvasHeight)
           ui.position.top = canvasHeight - $(this).height();  
    }                 
});
$('#dragme1').draggable({
    drag: function(evt,ui)
  {  
        // zoom fix
   //  ui.position.top = Math.round(ui.position.top / zoom);
     //ui.position.left = Math.round(ui.position.left / zoom);
        
        // don't let draggable to get outside of the canvas
       if (ui.position.left < 0) 
           ui.position.left = 0;
      if (ui.position.left + $(this).width() > canvasWidth)
           ui.position.left = canvasWidth - $(this).width();  
      if (ui.position.top < 0)
            ui.position.top = 0;
        if (ui.position.top + $(this).height() > canvasHeight)
           ui.position.top = canvasHeight - $(this).height();  
    }                 
});
```

```css
#canvas {
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
    border:1px solid #444;
    
}
#dragme {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:#f30;
    zoom:0.8;
}

#dragme1 {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    zoom:0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="canvas">
    <div id="dragme"></div>
     <div id="dragme1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of problems.

1. This part is problematic: `var zoom = $('#canvas').css('zoom');` because you attempted to use the canvas but your "zoom" css property is not for your `#canvas`.
2. Since the `zoom` property is not set in the inline css, you cannot get it from `.css` function. You need to use a computed style like `var zoom = getComputedStyle(this).zoom;`
3. The zoom interferes with finding the appropriate coordinates: for example, if the mouse moves by 10px, due to the zoom, it will only seem to move for 8px. It's very tricky to correct this issue (but I managed to do it nevertheless, by recording a value at the `start:` and performing some other mathematical operations. See below).
4. The restriction to the canvas: while the checks `ui.position.left < 0` and `ui.position.top < 0` continue to work, the other two don't work due to zooming.
   The other two should be `(ui.position.left + $(this).width()) * zoom > canvasWidth` and `(ui.position.top + $(this).height()) * zoom > canvasHeight`. Then again some more math operations to figure out the correct `ui.position.left` and `ui.position.top`
5. Even if the zoom was 1, your original code would not work properly for the blue object #dragme1: when the `position.top` equals 0 it is still not at the upper corner of the canvas, and when it is at the maximum value, it's already outside the canvas. This is due to due to having `position:relative`, which means its positioning is affected by the height of the red object. One way to solve it is by having them positioned absolutely, with the canvas positioned relative. And to get the appropriate starting position, the blue object starts with `top: 50px`, where 50px is the height of the red object.
6. After 1-5, I found that scrollY has some effects here, so I modified the startY calculations.

But then, there still seems to be an issue about "sudden jump" when the zoom is very different, say, `0.2`. Some time later I may (or may not) edit it to deal with those cases. But I think it is ok for a zoom level
of 0.8. And in any case this post has demonstrated how to get the basic features right.

It *may* possibly be cleaner to implement the dragging oneself using event listeners (if you know what you're doing) than being tied to jquery-ui (especially due to the issue #3 above).

```js
var canvasHeight = $('#canvas').height();
var canvasWidth = $('#canvas').width();

$('#dragme').draggable({
    start: function (evt, ui) {
        var zoom = getComputedStyle(this).zoom;
        $(this).data('startX', ui.position.left)
               .data('startY', ui.position.top - window.scrollY)
    },
    drag: function (evt, ui) {
        let diffX = ui.position.left - $(this).data('startX')
        let diffY = ui.position.top - $(this).data('startY')

        var zoom = getComputedStyle(this).zoom;

        ui.position.left = +$(this).data('startX') + diffX / zoom
        ui.position.top = +$(this).data('startY') + diffY / zoom

        if (ui.position.left < 0)
            ui.position.left = 0;
        if ((ui.position.left + $(this).width()) * zoom > canvasWidth)
            ui.position.left = canvasWidth / zoom - $(this).width();
        if (ui.position.top < 0)
            ui.position.top = 0;
        if ((ui.position.top + $(this).height()) * zoom > canvasHeight)
            ui.position.top = canvasHeight / zoom - $(this).height();
    }
});

$('#dragme1').draggable({
    start: function (evt, ui) {
        var zoom = getComputedStyle(this).zoom;
        $(this).data('startX', ui.position.left)
               .data('startY', ui.position.top - window.scrollY)
    },
    drag: function (evt, ui) {
        let diffX = ui.position.left - $(this).data('startX')
        let diffY = ui.position.top - $(this).data('startY')

        var zoom = getComputedStyle(this).zoom;

        ui.position.left = +$(this).data('startX') + diffX / zoom
        ui.position.top = +$(this).data('startY') + diffY / zoom

        if (ui.position.left < 0)
            ui.position.left = 0;
        if ((ui.position.left + $(this).width()) * zoom > canvasWidth)
            ui.position.left = canvasWidth / zoom - $(this).width();
        if (ui.position.top < 0)
            ui.position.top = 0;
        if ((ui.position.top + $(this).height()) * zoom > canvasHeight)
            ui.position.top = canvasHeight / zoom - $(this).height();
    }
});
```

```css
#canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    position: relative;
}

#dragme {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f30;
    zoom: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
}

#dragme1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    zoom: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="canvas">
    <div id="dragme"></div>
     <div id="dragme1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @qrsngky , thank you very much.  It worked for me, now I'm trying to enhance the feature by preventing the collision between two draggable elements  using the (https://github.com/dsbaars/jq-ui-draggable-collision) this plugin. Since the drag event was overridden by this plugin this solution is not working as expected. Can you please help me on this.